# htaccess change root to subdirectory, but allow only root url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess in my root directory, which allows me to use `/somepage` instead of `/subdir/somepage`. Now I want to disable usage of `/subdir/somepage` so only `/somepage` would be functional. Is there any way to do that?

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional rule to **block/disable** direct URIs with `/subdir/` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# send 403 if request if for /subdir/...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subdir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```